# Pushing items from JSON objects to dropdown in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I have a json file as

```
var myJson = {
   "Number of Devices":2,
   "Block Devices":{
      "bdev0":{
         "Backend_Device_Path":"/dev/ram1",
         "Capacity":"16777216",
         "Bytes_Written":9848,
         "timestamp":"4365093970",
         "IO_Operations":87204,
         "Guest_Device_Name":"vdb",
         "Bytes_Read":107619,
         "Guest_IP_Address":"192.168.26.88"
      },
      "bdev1":{
         "Backend_Device_Path":"/dev/ram2",
         "Capacity":"16777216",
         "Bytes_Written":10062,
         "timestamp":"9365093970",
         "IO_Operations":93789,
         "Guest_Device_Name":"vdb",
         "Bytes_Read":116524,
         "Guest_IP_Address":"192.168.26.100"
      }
   }
}
```

I want to push names of block devices in a dropdown menu. the names are bdev0 and bdev1 after looking at some example I tried the following code but I just returns [Object object] in the drop down

view

```
<select ng-model="selectedDevice" ng-options="item as devices['Block Devices'] for item in selectdevice">
    <option value="">Select Device</option>
   </select>
```

And controller

```
    .controller('timeSeriesCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $http) {

    $scope.selectedDevice = null;
    $scope.selectdevice = [];
    $scope.bytesRead = [];
    $scope.bytesWritten = [];
    $scope.IoOps = [];
    $scope.currentTime = [];
    var path = 'http://orbit5.ds.cs.umu.se:8888/vrio/debug/blk'


function getData(){
  $http.get(path)
  .success(function(data){
    $scope.devices = data
    angular.forEach($scope.devices['Block Devices'], function(value, key){

           $scope.selectdevice = key;
})


  })
}

getData();





  });
```

Comment: You want `ng-options="item.displayName as item for item in devices['Block Devices']"`

Comment: it still just returns [Object object]

Comment: Note: _please use services for making HTTP requests_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove all of the code for the `forEach` and just use the `(key,value)` syntax for `ng-options`

```
function getData(){
  $http.get(path)
  .success(function(data){
    $scope.devices = data
    //angular.forEach($scope.devices['Block Devices'], function(value, key){
       //$scope.selectdevice = key;
    //   value.key = key;
    //})
  });
```

In html:

```
<select ng-model="selectedDevice" 
      ng-options="item as key  for (key,item) in devices['Block Devices'] ">
    <option value="">Select Device</option>
</select>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/4mqFJ/6/

Comment: Gives me error Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'as' is an unexpected token at column 10 of the expression [item.key as devices['Block Devices']] starting at [as devices['Block Devices']].

Comment: So i updated it i didn't even see how you were setting devices.    I'm assuming i'm showing the right set.

Comment: Sorry about that Just updated the code you can see now how I set devices

Comment: I think i know what you want to do and I simplified it dramatically.

Comment: your original answer did not had (key, value) trick. Its got updated after I posted my answer. I verified this just now.

Comment: You are using `ng-repeat` I'm using `ng-options`.  Nice try.  I added a fiddle and tested it and as soon as i saw that he was trying to display the key versus the keys in the actual nested objects I simplified my syntax.  You can go troll some where else.

Answer (score 1):

`object.toString() = [object object].` [Object.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

You can use the `(key, content)` syntax to display keys.

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem">
      <option ng-repeat="(key, content) in myjson['Block Devices']" value="{{item}}">{{key}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: No need for `ng-repeat` you can just use `ng-options` to do the same.